# Best approximation of meters to degrees - North America

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system

I am working with the [st_dwthin](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) with srid 4326 in North America.

I would like to write down the **distance_of_srid** in meters.

Which function or method will be the most accurate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it this way, by projecting your geometries which are given in WGS84 (EPSG:4326) into your preferred local Cartesian coordinate reference frame (in order to have metric distances):

```
SELECT 
  ST_Within(
    ST_Transform(<WGS84geomA>, <your_local_srid>),
    ST_Transform(<WGS84geomB>, <your_local_srid>)
  )
```

If necessary, you can search for any CRS on the EPSG registry, e.g. at: https://epsg.org/search/map if you prefer using a map based selection, as for example some NAD projections:

[image]

You can also check how the [`ST_Distance()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) function behave when fed with geography features:

> For geography types defaults to return the minimum [geodesic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic) distance between two geographies in meters, compute on the spheroid determined by the SRID. If use_spheroid is false, a faster spherical calculation is used.

Or also [`ST_Spheroid_Distance()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic).

E.g.:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
    ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-73.935242 40.730610)',4326) AS NewYork,
    ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-122.431297 37.773972)',4326) AS SanFransisco
)
SELECT 
  ST_DistanceSpheroid(
    NewYork,
    SanFransisco,
    'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]'
  ) AS "SpheroidDistance",
  ST_Distance(
    NewYork::geography,
    SanFransisco::geography
  ) AS "GreatCircleDistance"
FROM cte;

 SpheroidDistance  | GreatCircleDistance 
-------------------+---------------------
 4145618.315899794 |    4145618.31589979
(1 row)
```

See: https://epsg.io/4326 for the definition of the WGS84 spheroid.

Fun fact:

[image]

G.maps is roughly giving  4'135.55 km for this distance and you can see the the curvature induced by the [Web Mercator projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator_projection).

The same distance computed using the Ellipsoidal radio button of the measure tool in [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/):

[image]

whereas if you tick the Cartesian radio, it "wrongly" gives 5'415.276 km.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `GEOGRAPHY` data type to measure geoidal distances globally.

Functions providing a signature for this type accept any threshold parameters, and return their measurements, in *meter* (or *square meter* for aerial measurements) and are calculated either on a spherical or spheroidal (most accurate) Earth model,  with axii parameters as per the underlying reference ellipsoid (defaults to that of `EPSG:4326`).

*Compared to their planar counterparts, these calculations have a higher execution cost due to their higher complexity.*

You can cast geographically referenced `GEOMETRY` objects at query time, i.e.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  <table>
WHERE
  ST_DWithin(
    <geom>::GEOGRAPHY,
    <reference_geom>::GEOGRAPHY,
    <distance_in_meter>
    [, TRUE|FALSE]  -- use_spheroid
  )
;
```

---

Note that this casted type (`::GEOGRAPHY`) is not covered by a spatial index on the `GEOMETRY` column; you may want to add a *functional index* on the casted type, i.e.

```
CREATE INDEX
  ON <table>
  USING GIST ( (<geom>::GEOGRAPHY) )  -- double parentheses
;

-- VACUUM ANALYZE <table>;
```